# Looking for child elements in a TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am writing a custom TagHelper that should change its behavior based on what child elements its owner tag has. This will be used for substituting custom html elements in a localized string.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```html
<h2 locale-key="Hello, %1!">
    <span class="bold" locale-parameter="1">@userName</span>
</h2>
```

In the example above, the TagHelper for LocaleKey will change the content of the `<h2>` tag to a localized string. If this is a simple string with no parameters, then I can just simply use `output.Content.SetHtmlContent()` in the TagHelper to set the `h2`'s content to the string. However in this case, the localized string has a parameter (`%1`), and I want the corresponding child element (`<span parameter="1">`) to be substituted in the final output. So the final rendered html would look like this:

```html
<h2>Hello, <span class="bold">Lázár Zsolt</span>!<h2/>
```

To achieve this, I should be able to see all the child elements in the DOM from the LocaleKey TagHelper, so I can generate the correct HTML code. In the TagHelper's `ProcessAsync` method I can access the `TagHelperContext` and the `TagHelperOutput`, but I couldn't find any information about child elements in either of these objects while debugging. Is this possible somehow?

Another approach is to leave the string as is, with the `%1` parameter key, and then use the child ParameterTagHelper to substitute itself into the parameterized string. To do this, I'd have to see the siblings of the current tag from the TagHelper.

Recursion would also be fun (e.g. the `<span>` is also localized and has its own parameters), but for the scope of this question, I'd be happy if I could get this to work without recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted too soon again... There is a `GetChildContentAsync()` method in `TagHelperOutput` that will... get the child content asynchronously.